# Linq query to select next id from a database table

Tags: c#, linq

is there any way to select the next object from a database table without knowing its' `Id`?

The database table looks like that and it's called `Jobs`:

```
Id | ScheduleId | DateHappened | Status
 1 |   150      | 2014-05-30   | Done
 2 |   150      | 2014-06-10   | Done
 3 |   150      | 2014-06-13   | Done
```

I am trying to get the Id of each `Job` and use it to insert it in a log table. I know that this is some sort of a "against the rules" request, but at this stage I can't afford to make any big changes.

I know that in this case I can select the first and the last elements by using the `.First()` and `.Last()` functions, but what about anything in between?

Comment: *"I am trying to get the Id of each `Job`"* - wouldn't you need to select all items then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're assuming that the jobs are returned in order of `id`, which might be a big assumption...

However, you also mention `.First()` and `.Last()` and have tagged "Linq", so I assume you've already got your data from the database in some way. I'll assume that you have an `IQueryable` called `queryResult` that you are calling `.First()` and `.Last()` on for the remainder of this answer...

If you just want to go through every record, you perhaps don't need Linq at all: just use a `foreach`:

```
foreach (var row in queryResult)
{
    ....
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want every method, you might be able to use Linq's `.Skip()`:

```
queryResult.Skip(10).First() // gives you the 11th record
```

Or, if you just want to log all of the IDs as a single item, you could use Linq's `Select` to get a list of just the IDs:

```
queryResult.Select(x => x.Id)
```

If all you're interested in is the ID, but you need to loop individually, then you can potentially use the result of this `.Select` in combination with the other solutions to make your code more efficient. If you're using an ORM with deferred execution (like EF) then a query like this is more efficient than pulling the entire database and then using a `foreach`:

```
var ids = queryResult.Select(x => x.Id);
foreach (var id in ids) 
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Using the `foreach` actually passes perfectly, I can't believe I didn't think of it earlier..

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want all IDs from all the jobs:

```
db.Jobs.Select(j => j.ID).ToList()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this one:

```
var ids = db.Jobs.Select(x=>x.Id);
```

or

```
var ids = (from job in db.Jobs
          select job.Id);
```